# How can I change my scattered box plot in Plotly Python?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, boxplot

How can I change this plot or kind of plot so as to have comparison of gender? Because currently as you can see on the picture boxes in my box plot are scattered.

```
data=pd.DataFrame({"Sex":["male", "male", "male", "female", "female", "female"], "Credit amount":[2000, 3000, 4000, 2500, 3300, 6000]})
```

My code:

```
df_good = data[data["Sex"] == 'male']
df_bad = data[data["Sex"] == 'female']

trace0 = go.Box(
    y=df_good["Credit amount"],
    x=df_good["Sex"],
    name='Male',
    marker=dict(
        color='#3D9970'
    )
)

trace1 = go.Box(
    y=df_bad['Credit amount'],
    x=df_bad['Sex'],
    name='Female',
    marker=dict(
        color='#FF4136'
    )
)
    
data = [trace0, trace1]

layout = go.Layout(
    yaxis=dict(
        title='Checking distribution'
    ),
    boxmode='group'
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

py.iplot(fig, filename='box-age-cat')
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a data sample.

Comment: data=pd.DataFrame({"Sex":["male", "male", "male", "female", "female", "female"], "Credit amount":[2000, 3000, 4000, 2500, 3300, 6000]})

Comment: In the *question* if you wouldn't mind.

Comment: done ;) please help me

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're aiming to do here. You say you'd like to compare genders. But that's exactly what your plot does, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you could improve in your code. Not last your choice of names bad/good related to sex. Anyway it looks to me that you want to get something like [distplot](https://plot.ly/python/distplot/). Regarding your example you could simply do this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
df = pd.DataFrame({"Sex":["male", "male", "male", "female", "female", "female"],
                   "Credit amount":[2000, 3000, 4000, 2500, 3300, 6000]})

fig = px.box(df,
             x="Sex",
             y="Credit amount",
             color="Sex",
             points="all")
fig.show()
```

[image]